# jquery remove id in (div)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want remove id in (div) with jQuery, can help me ?

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="margin-pack">

    <div class="pack">
        <a data-tab="tab-1">pack1-cu</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pack">
        <a data-tab="tab-2"pack2-cu</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pack" id="active">
        <a data-tab="tab-3">pack3-cu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want, click in div (pack), id (active) remove with jQuery cod.
And click other div (pack), id (active) add.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself, StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: XY Problem:  whatever you need this for is incorrect - you don't want to add/remove `id` - what you should be doing is add/remove **a class** and setup your css / other rules accordingly `.active { color: yellow; }` and `$(".active")...` then it's a clean case of `$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pack").click(function() {
    $(".pack").removeAttr("id")
    $(this).attr('id', 'active');
  });
});
```

```css
#active {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pack">
  <a data-tab="tab-1">pack1-cu</a>
</div>
<div class="pack">
  <a data-tab="tab-2">pack2-cu</a>
</div>
<div class="pack" id="active">
  <a data-tab="tab-3">pack3-cu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice and Thank you dear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example for removing an id:

```
$('div#active').removeAttr('id');
```

And you can use this example for adding an id:

```
$('div.pack').attr('id', 'active');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#active").removeAttr("id");`
 just use this

Comment: `just use this` is a very weak explanation, also your answer only solves half the problems